# Relative parent DIV to inherit the width of absolute child DIV

Tags: css

I am trying to position a child DIV at the bottom of a parent DIV, but I would also like the contents of the child DIV to help dictate the dimensions of the parent DIV. As I have it right now, the child DIV doesn't affect the width/height of the parent DIV.

**Here is a sample of my code:**

```css
#parent {
    background-color:#222;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
}
    
#child {
    background-color:#444;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <h3>Top Aligned Title</h3>
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is I would forget the absolute/relative CSS rules and simply create a table within the parent DIV which would allow me to achieve both bottom alignment and content that dictate the parent
div dimensions.

However, I'd like to know if there a way to do this in CSS and without having to set the width of the parent DIV.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you want #parent to take it's width from #child so be 100px wide? Id so then make your #parent div "display: inline-block" and see if that is what you're after.

Comment: Yes. Although the width of the child DIV in this example is specified in the CSS, the width in my actual project is dictated dynamically in the JS code.

Comment: This sort of thing? http://jsfiddle.net/Avww9/

Comment: The title in your example is dictating the width of the parent DIV. If the the title weren't as wide as the child DIV, then the parent DIV would still be the width of the title and not the child DIV.

Comment: Fair enough - pretty sure what you want can't be done with css alone then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer is that what you are asking basically can't be done with pure CSS / HTML. (at least without tables) You'd need Javascript that would read #child's width/height and then do the calculation you want to do (I don't know) and set a new height/width to #parent.

Otherwise, if you mean that you want #child's height/width to change according to its content, of course this is native CSS, just set it's height/width to auto and then start adding text inside it you'll see it will start growing to fit your content inside.

As the #child is positioned absolute, then it is taken OUT of the normal flow of the document, therefore it will not affect the #parent.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of. I guess I can set the width of the parent DIV dynamically once I know the contents of the child DIV. Alternatively I guess I can use the table tag, the great-standby to getting things done quickly in HTML.

Comment: Well, if you really think about it, your design has some "logic" behind it, therefore -at least for now- , JS (jQuery) is the way to go..

Answer (score 3):

With modern CSS, this is doable.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <h3>Top Aligned Title</h3>
    <div id="child">
        <p>CHILD ELEMENT</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {
    background:red;
    height: 500px;
    position:relative;
}
#child {
    background:green;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/bpe5s6x3/

1. `transform:translateY(-100%);` is the trick. It's math is based on the `element`'s `box-model`.
2. You could also combine `top:50%;` with `transform:translateY(-50%);` to center it.
3. You can swap `top` for `left` and `translateY` for `translateX` to position the element horizontally.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work for me: parent is wider than child

Comment: Which part of the code involves the width "transfer" from child to parent?

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with `flex` and zero-width/height.

I've recently come up with the following solution (for width):

```css
#parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  background: #518cff;
  color: #fff;
}

#child-wrapper {
  height: 0; /* This can also be max-height, but height is just enough */
}

#child {
  transform: translateY(-100%); /* If you need to align child to the bottom */
  
  background: #b40000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <h3>Top Aligned Title</h3>
  <div id="child-wrapper"> <!-- This is the solution -->
    <div id="child">
      Child's content that is longer than parent's
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You missed the `absolute` position within child element.

Answer (score -2):

Here you go

**HTML:**

```
<main id="parent">
  <div class="popup">Top Aligned Title
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {
  width: 120px;
}

.popup {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 48px;
}

.content {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8L9votay/

Comment: You are hard-coding the width of the parent as opposed to inheriting the width of the absolute positioned child. Thus, this is not an answer to the question.