# Set parent width to width of child aligned to bottom

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the width of a div element to the width of it's longest child element, which in this case happens to be a div that I want locked to the bottom of the parent div. I am also not using a fixed height for the parent, because I do not know how big the children will need to be

Here is my html/css:

HTML:

```
<div id ="header-right">
   <div id="content1"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header-right{
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px; /*The actual width is unknown, this is just for example*/
}
#content1{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
#footer{
    background-color: cyan;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 300px; /*Also an unknown value*/
    height: 25px;
}
```

You can have a look at this jfiddle to see what happens:
https://jsfiddle.net/rkdqp9m5/2/

You can see the container div ignores the footer, since it is absolutely positioned.

However, if I do not use absolute positioning for the footer, then I cannot lock the footer to the bottom of the div, as you can see in this jfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rkdqp9m5/3/

I want to lock the footer to the bottom of the container, but I also want the parent's width to be based off the footer. I do not want to use tables for this, and I do not wan to used fixed widths or heights, as the container's and the footer's dimensions will be based off of images whose widths I do not know.

Edit: I would also like to keep this strictly in HTML/CSS, if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're OK with browser requirements of [`flexbox`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), you could do:

```css
#header-right {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#content1 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
#footer {
    background-color: cyan;
    width: 300px;
    height: 25px;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-right">
    <div id="content1"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kr1x2r9r/)**</kbd> with all the necessary vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help: [Relative parent DIV to inherit the width of absolute child DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835610/relative-parent-div-to-inherit-the-width-of-absolute-child-div)

What it suggests is that you can't use pure CSS, but you can use Javascript to achieve what you're trying to do.