# How to set the maximum width from relative and absolute positioned parts of container?

Tags: html, css, combobox

*Background: I try to implement custom `select` widget in order to have `option` accepting any content.*

This is somewhat follow-up to the question like [Relative parent DIV to inherit the width of absolute child DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835610/relative-parent-div-to-inherit-the-width-of-absolute-child-div) because here I also have container and 2 children -- one visible all the time, and the other shown only when open (this one is absolute positioned).

Let's say I have animal selection:

```
dog
---
cat
dog
elephant
```

So for this example the visible part should be as wide as "elephant" needs, but since it is hidden and it is absolute positioned, this part is not taken into account, as the effect it is as narrow as "dog" demands.

I've read it might be possible with the tables, so I tried, but I always get the same effect -- the first part width is calculated independently from the second part. With table it is actually even worse because the shown part dictates the width for the second part, so when I open the drop-down part I see items squeezed.

Maybe there some new CSS features that would make it possible?

Comment: why not make the shown part wider depending on your elements list, else you would need to get the width of the largest element on the list and assign it to the shown element through JS

Comment: @Dhia  "why not make the shown part wider depending on your elements list" -- you mean like hardcoded width? I am looking for dynamic approach, so UI would handle itself :-) As for JS I was "afraid" it is the way, but given how much tricks you can pull off with CSS I was hoping for something JS-free.